# How to Use Jquery change Function Value In Another Function Is Any Way To Use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want something like this I want to get on change function value in the second function.

```
var ID = 0;
$.("something").change(function() {
  var ID = $(this).val();
});

function findPaper() { **
  alert(ID); **
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Paper/findPaperPost",
    type: "get",
    data: {
      id: ID
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  });
```

How can I do this any possible way to do this thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the function inside the event and pass the id as an argument like :

```
$.("something").change(function() {
  findPaper($(this).val(), 'value2', 'value3');
});

function findPaper(id, val2, val3) {
  console.log( val2, val3);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Paper/findPaperPost",
    type: "get",
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: if i want to pass more two parameter to this function what should i do ? means that  i have two more change value how i can pass two more to this function.